# Ubersuggest continuously finds newly created spammy backlinks to my site

Tags: seo, backlinks, negative-seo, disavow-links

I found some of the spam links in Ubersuggest backlinks report for my website.. The spam backlinks increase daily as measured by this tool.

I removed all URLs from Google Search Console as well as disavow the backlinks there.  However, they are still showing in Ubersuggest. How can I resolve this issue stop spam backlinks from being continuously created?

Answer (score 2):

All websites are going to obtain backlinks that are spammy in nature if they have been online long enough. However, Google knows the difference between a spammy link and a clean link with good authority. Google usually takes those spammy links out of the equation anyway. I would not worry about disavowing them unless I see a specific reason for doing so.